# how adding global function in backbone.js accessible from multiple templates?

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js

I have created two templates  one for table and another for form inputs. The function which is in one template is not accessible from the other template . I want one global function which is accessible from both the template . I am new to backbone world . So is there  any provision to do this ? Or is there any way access the function on one template from the another ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways of achieving this.

**1. Add to Backbone directly**

The simplest, but perhaps least desirable from a maintenance point of view, would be to add the function as a property of the `Backbone` object:

```
Backbone.myFunction = function (...) { ... };
```

**2. Register a templating helper**

The second option, depending on your templating engine of choice, you might be able to register helpers. Example:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("myHelper", function (...) { ... });
```

**3. Use dependency injection**

A third option, if you are using something like [require](http://requirejs.org/), would be to define the functions in a common dependency, and add it as a dependency to both views.